# Symfony2 access control with multiple role requirement

Tags: symfony, access-control

On my site, except some spesific pages (login, register, pwd reset) users are required to login. I have implemented `remember me` feature and it works well.

What I would like to achieve is, for administration pages, users should have `admin role and not remembered`. To check this requirement I used `allow_if` in the relevant access_control rule, however it denies my admin user's access, although session is not remembered and I can confirm that session has `UsernamePasswordToken` on debug toolbar.

My access_control rules are as follows: (**4th one doesn't work**)

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, allow_if: "has_role('ROLE_ADMIN') and has_role('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')" }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
```

If I remove `and has_role('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')` part from the relevant access control rule, user can pass authorization so the problem seems to be this part.

What is the problem with `has_role('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')` ?

> Symfony Version: 2.7.5

Comment: What does the profiler say? Has your specific user the role `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` or maybe `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`? Fully is only when the user provider username and password during this specific session.

Comment: As I stated on the question I can verify that my session has `UsernamePasswordToken`. If it was a remembered session it would be `RememberMeToken`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround to fix the issue.

[How to use Expressions in Security, Routing, Services, and Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/expression/expressions.html) cookbook article on official website has a relevant section and states the possible use of `is_remember_me()` and `is_fully_authenticated()` methods for checking the existence `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` and `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` roles  respective.

> **is_remember_me is different than checking IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED**
>
> The is_remember_me and is_authenticated_fully functions are similar to   using IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED and IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY with the isGranted function - but they are not the same. The following shows the difference:

```
use Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\Expression;
// ...

$ac = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');
$access1 = $ac->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED');

$access2 = $ac->isGranted(new Expression(
'is_remember_me() or is_fully_authenticated()'
));
```

> Here, $access1 and $access2 will be the same value. Unlike the behavior of IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED and IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, the is_remember_me function only returns true if the user is authenticated via a remember-me cookie and is_fully_authenticated only returns true if the user has actually logged in during this session (i.e. is full-fledged).

Using that documentation section, I revised my access control rules as follows and it works now:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, allow_if: "has_role('ROLE_ADMIN') and is_fully_authenticated()" }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
```

However, I still think that this is an issue and is not the expected behaviour. So, I opened an issue in the official issue tracker:

**Github Issue:** [#16096 - Expression engine has_role() function can't process implicit roles](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/16096)

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation:](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#security-authorization-access-control)

> Add Code to Deny Access There are two ways to deny access to
>   something:
>
> 1. access_control in security.yml allows you to protect URL patterns (e.g. /admin/*). This is easy, but less flexible;
> 2. in your code via the security.authorization_checker service.

You're trying to use the first way, but it's possible to make only by second.

You need to perform an authorization checking in your controller by putting inside it a code

```
if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
    throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
}
```

Also you could use SensioFrameworkExtraBundle and just add an annotation to your controller

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

...

/**
 * @Security("is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')")
 */
public function showAction()
{
}
```

Comment: Dmitry, could you please elaborate on why `it's possible to make only by second`? IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY is an implicit role which is assigned to users by symfony. Therefore, it works when you have an access_control rule such as: `{ path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }`. So why doesn't it work in an expression?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that expressions are supported in security configuration files? I looked through the documentation and took a look at a code parsing it and I don't see anything about this possibility. So that's why I think it's possible only in second way - because if you need to involve some advanced logic - you need to use authorization limitations by controllers.

Comment: Expression support is documented on [Securing by an expression](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html#securing-by-an-expression) section of "How Does the Security access_control Work?" cookbook article. Also, it is not about the expressions. `{ path: ^/admin, allow_if: "has_role('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')" }` doesn't work either.